# Given an EmbaseID, is there any way to programmatically retrieve the abstract?

Tags: data-request, api, medical

Given an `Embase ID` (= ID to identify a record in [Embase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embase)), is there any way to programmatically retrieve the abstract of the corresponding research paper?